# the bind method prompted that No overload matches this call

Tags: typescript

When I use the bind method without passing parameters,Typescript doesn't seem to understand what I mean, that No overload matches this call.

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#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%201TSDLLn-YjJVgAJmlQA)

```js
const map = {
  say(this:Person, a:string) {
    console.log(this.words[0], a);
  },
  work(this:Person, a:number, b:number) {
    console.log(this.words[1], a + b);
  },
  // more methods.... their this points to Person
};

class Person {
  words = [
    'hello world',
    'i working',
  ]

  get<T extends keyof typeof map>(key:T):typeof map[T] {
    // Error: No overload matches this call.
    return map[key].bind(this)
  }
}

const ins = new Person();
const f = ins.get('work');

// The 'this' context of type 'void' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'Person'.
f(1,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go,

you are trying to use an object as a map, you would need to assign object value keys like work : function().... but instead you can do this.

```
const map : { [ key: string ]: Function; } = {
    [ 'say' ]: function(this:Person, a:string) {
    console.log(this.words[0], a);
  },
  [ 'work' ] : function(this:Person, a:number, b:number) {
    console.log(this.words[1], a + b);
  },
  // more methods.... their this points to Person
};

class Person {
  words = [
    'hello world',
    'i working',
  ]

  get<T extends keyof typeof map>(key:T):typeof map[T] {
    // Error: No overload matches this call.
    return map[key].bind(this)
  }
}

const ins = new Person();
const f = ins.get('work');

type 'Person'.
f(1,2)
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgQwA4wFwwN4wNowNYCmAnutAE4CWYA5jALroBiArmMFBeANwwC%20MAXkwAoGGJwwA5BARFJ9dADNW7TmAAUUABYUIqAAoEyEcABoYCVOSrUAlCPExQkEABsCAOlchqmnRA8AdxAyABMIbAAGOnMEWy5RPlNE3Elgsjx5OjQYZTYOcD9dAyMTMFjUMGY4ACMjcxrK6rqyewxEsWcTdy8fIoD08OwARhiLGABqGBr4xN5ksQB6RfgQgngCbRBwj12PGG0CCjID-xgkECooCAOQGENjcGFeBOFgVwQIG4eyhxhBm5CbAdKRaAiubz-EKuUKSBbiSQUKEZGxwxJ0YSJaibAA8ABUYAQAB5QAhgcL4YggRQHIhIAjU%20DIAB86kIJDxtlQUDpDJpiCQ2Dx2XajmWMAAomQyCF0AA5O4gABuRm8CFCTKgwDBN20uicCAhHhBZE2zDIYCZgvZdA8NSooX6tjmz0xXVgVEBMDABEC91KhVm7tyghgno82Kg6jSIUys2E4rxYKkeog8mcpJJMEZPPpUiVl1hYZuYBAsE%20EAo1DACBq7luGy2sJuklT8hzvKkP3AkmNinUw1MACZbEA)
output is "i working" "3"